Semi circular gauge progress bar in react
enter image description here
I want to make semi circle gauge chart(progress bar) shown in the image above.
here are the key requirements:

A semi-circle shape with a progress bar that fills the border.
The ends of the progress bar should be rounded.
The progress color should be a gradient.

My Stack: React, TypeScript, Styled-components
Any code snippets or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I googled 'rounded semi-circle progress bar'...
